# WCF Ajax Service Return Value

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Ajax-Service hosted within a Web Application (.NET 4.0, C#). I can successfully call it and get a value back. The problem is my return value is encoded in JSON. I am trying to return a string of XML (GeoRSS technically) that I want to feed into the OpenLayers library. How can I get the WCF service to send the return value not in JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140460/returning-json-and-xml-format-from-a-net-3-5-wcf-web-service-rest) should be what you are looking for. Its in 3.5 but the implementation should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the ResponseFormat property of the [WebInvoke] or [WebGet] to WebMessageFormat.Xml, and you'll get XML output.